# Deploy locally with Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops

Please help,

**The aim**

I'm trying out Visual Studio Team Services, having previously done all my deployment by copying files by hand to my server.

I'm using the standard Build template to get started.

I've got a local VSagent running on my server and when I look into its work folders I see all the relevant files from my Git source, as well as a `bin` folder.

If I point IIS to this folder, the site loads correctly.

**The pain**

However, I feel uncomfortable about pointing a live site to a folder whose path is `C:\vstsagent\_work\2\s\xxxxxxx` as I have no idea what else the agent might do to that path. Maybe it'll decide to delete everything on a whim.

So now I'm trying to copy the files somewhere else, as a final step.

I have added a File Copy step, but it only copies the source and not the `bin` folder. Why?

If I try to 'publish artifacts' which sounds like the right thing to do it doesn't give me the option to take artifacts from my MVC project, only bits and pieces from other related projects. Why?

**In essence**: how do I get the VS agent to copy the necessary files to run my website into a folder of my choice?

Being a simple .net MVC developer I don't really know what artifacts are and I'm struggling to find any documentation that doesn't suck me into a vortex about MSBuild and Azure and so on which I've never had to worry about before - just press F5 and it works!

Please help!

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://blog.ehn.nu/2016/03/using-web-deploy-in-visual-studio-team-services-release-management/) can be of some help, it walks through using web deploy to publish the artifacts of the build.

Comment: Ok - so I need to go down the route of a Publish profile? I've tried that and get all kinds of odd errors but perhaps I need to pursue that route. Have you found it to be useful/essential?